Validate an email address whether it is valid or invalid based on condition
I have a requirement to validate an email address whether it is valid or invalid based on one condition.
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\/\=\?\^\`\{\|\}\~]+)@((\[a-z]{1,3}\.[a-z]{1,3}\.[a-z]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})

Create a function in SQL Sever Management Studio for the below mentioned logic as valid or invalid email?
Local Part of Email:
([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.\!\#\$\%\&\'\*\+\/\=\?\^\{|}~]+)

This part matches the local part of an email address (the part before the @ sign). It allows letters (both uppercase and lowercase), digits, and several special characters like _, -, ., !, #, $, %, &, ', *, +, /, =, ?, ^, , {, |, }, and ~`. It requires at least one of these characters.
Domain Part:
@((\[a-z]{1,3}\.[a-z]{1,3}\.[a-z]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))

This matches the @ symbol followed by the domain part of the email. The domain part can be:

A sequence of 1 to 3 letters followed by a period, repeated up to three times (e.g., com. or co.uk.), or
A more general format where the domain consists of one or more groups of letters, digits, or hyphens followed by a period (e.g., example.com. or sub.example.com.).

Top-Level Domain (TLD):
([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})

This matches the top-level domain (TLD) of the email address. It allows for a TLD that is 2 to 4 letters long (e.g., .com, .info, .org) or a TLD that is 1 to 3 digits long (e.g., .123).
I tried the below function but it is giving not valid email for "asidhu@wiz-tec.ca". So require solution to rectify this function.
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.IsValidEmail (@Email NVARCHAR(254))
RETURNS BIT
AS
BEGIN
    -- Local variables
    DECLARE @AtSymbolPosition INT,
            @LastDotPosition INT,
            @LocalPart NVARCHAR(128),
            @DomainPart NVARCHAR(128),
            @TopLevelDomain NVARCHAR(10);

    -- Find the position of the '@' symbol
    SET @AtSymbolPosition = CHARINDEX('@', @Email);
    
    -- Check if '@' exists and it's not the first or last character
    IF @AtSymbolPosition < 2 OR @AtSymbolPosition = LEN(@Email)
        RETURN 0;

    -- Extract local part and domain part
    SET @LocalPart = LEFT(@Email, @AtSymbolPosition - 1);
    SET @DomainPart = SUBSTRING(@Email, @AtSymbolPosition + 1, LEN(@Email));

    -- Check if there's at least one dot ('.') in the domain part
    SET @LastDotPosition = CHARINDEX('.', @DomainPart);
    IF @LastDotPosition < 2 OR @LastDotPosition = LEN(@DomainPart)
        RETURN 0;

    -- Ensure the domain part has valid characters (alphanumeric, '-' and '.')
    IF PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9-.]%', @DomainPart) > 0
        RETURN 0;

    -- Domain cannot start or end with '-' or '.'
    IF LEFT(@DomainPart, 1) = '-' OR LEFT(@DomainPart, 1) = '.' OR RIGHT(@DomainPart, 1) = '-' OR RIGHT(@DomainPart, 1) = '.'
        RETURN 0;

    -- Ensure hyphen is not next to a dot in the domain part
    IF @DomainPart LIKE '%.%-%' OR @DomainPart LIKE '%-.%'
        RETURN 0;

    -- Extract top-level domain (TLD) after the last dot in the domain
    SET @LastDotPosition = LEN(@DomainPart) - CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(@DomainPart)) + 1;
    SET @TopLevelDomain = SUBSTRING(@DomainPart, @LastDotPosition + 1, LEN(@DomainPart));

    -- Ensure TLD length is between 2 and 4 characters
    IF LEN(@TopLevelDomain) < 2 OR LEN(@TopLevelDomain) > 4
        RETURN 0;

    -- Local part validation: alphanumeric and allowed special characters
    IF PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9!#$%&''*+/=?^_`{|}~.-]%', @LocalPart) > 0
        RETURN 0;

    -- If all checks pass, return valid (1)
    RETURN 1;
END
GO


How is SSMS, an IDE-like application related here? We need to know the data engine you are using. Tagging SSMS for your data engine is like tagging Visual Studio for your programming language.

Though, validating an email feels like application logic, not database logic.

What are you trying to do? Validate an actual email, including headers and attachments, or an email address? Sounds like the later, but please make sure you state clearly what you are doing. Is this part of a signup process? In that case I'd just go with ^[^@]+@[^@]+$ to catch typos. Even if you cover all invalid email addresses (which you currently don't) the address can be syntactically valid and still not in use. Just send a confirmation link and let people click that. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/how-can-i-validate-an-email-address-using-a-regular-expression

I don't think the dup is correct, thats not trying to use SQL...

You're asking us to debug your function for you... whats stopping you from debugging it?

The easy way to debug functions is to copy its code to a new query window, declare input parameter as a variable and set it to the "problem value". Then add PRINT @varible statements to get the state of your variables.

Don't waste time validating emails more than the absolutely necessary. A basic validation of @ and some text in front and back is enough because email might still fail later anyway even if it looks good and you have fired all those electrons in vain
